# dynamic plotting in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, matplotlib

I have been developing a GUI for reading continuous data from a serial port. After reading the data, some calculations are made and the results will be plotted and refreshed (aka dynamic plotting). I use the wx backend provided in the matplotlib for this purposes. To do this, I basically use an array to store my results, in which I keep appending it to, after each calculation, and replot the whole graph. To make it "dynamic", I just set the x-axis lower and upper limits for each iteration. Something like found in:

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/

The problem, however, is that since the data is continuous, and if I keep plotting it, eventually the system memory will run out and system will crash. Is there any other way I can plot my result continuously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To do this, I basically use an array
>   to store my results, in which I keep
>   appending it to

Try limiting the size of this array, either by deleting old data or by deleting every n-th entry (the screen resolution will prevent all entries to be displayed anyway). I assume you write all the data to disk so you won't lose anything.

Also, analise your code for memory leaks. Stuff you use and don't need anymore but that doesn't get garbage-collected because you still have a reference to it.

Comment: I have been thinking of similar thing; deleting/limiting the size of the array. You are right, besides plotting, the data will be saved into a file in the disk. Still, if possible, I would like to create a feature, in which, the user can view the whole/certain range of plotting (in addition to dynamic plotting which I set the x-axis limit).

Answer (score 1):

I have created such a component with pythons Tkinter. The source is [here](http://code.google.com/p/asuro-syd/source/browse/lib/pysyd/SydPlot.py).

Basically, you have to keep the plotted data *somewhere*. You cannot keep an infinite amount of data points in memory, so you either have to save it to disk or you have to overwrite old data points.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, infinite looping/appending is a disaster. Thanks for sharing the code, will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Data and representation of data are two different things. You might want to store your data to disk if it's important data to be analyzed later, but only keep a fixed period of time or the last N points for display purposes. You could even let the user pick the time frame to be displayed.

Comment: Maybe something like this?
1. Dynamic plotting: fixed x-range, limit the size of array by deleting unused values.
2. Every data being write into a file in disk
3. User defined plotting: read from the previously-saved-in-the-disk data and plot it

Comment: Something like that. In point 1, you probably mean "oldest" rather than "unused" :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually ran into this problem (more of a mental block, actually...).

First of all I copy-pasted some wx Plot code from [wx Demo Code](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Using%20wxPython%20Demo%20Code).

What I do is keep a live log of a value, and compare it to two markers (min and max, shown as red and green dotted lines) (but I will make these 2 markers optional - hence the optional parameters).

In order to implement the live log, I first wanted to use the deque class, but since the data is in tuple mode (x,y coordinates) I gave up and just tried to rewrite the entire parameter list of tuples: see _update_coordinates.

It works just fine for keeping track of the last 100-10,000 plots. Would have also included a printscreen, but I'm too much of a noob at stackoverflow to be allowed :))

My live parameter is updated every 0.25 seconds over a 115kbps UART.

The trick is at the end, in the custom refresh method!

Here is most of the code:

```
class DefaultPlotFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, ymin=0, ymax=MAXIMUM_PLOTS, minThreshold=None, 
             maxThreshold=None, plotColour='blue',
             title="Default Plot Frame", 
             position=(10,10),
             backgroundColour="yellow", frameSize=(400,300)):

        self.minThreshold = minThreshold
        self.maxThreshold = maxThreshold
        self.frame1 = wx.Frame(None, title="wx.lib.plot", id=-1, size=(410, 340), pos=position)
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self.frame1)
        self.panel1.SetBackgroundColour(backgroundColour)
        self.ymin = ymin
        self.ymax = ymax
        self.title = title
        self.plotColour = plotColour

        self.lines = [None, None, None]                

       # mild difference between wxPython26 and wxPython28        
       if wx.VERSION[1] < 7:
           self.plotter = plot.PlotCanvas(self.panel1, size=frameSize)
       else:
           self.plotter = plot.PlotCanvas(self.panel1)
       self.plotter.SetInitialSize(size=frameSize)
       # enable the zoom feature (drag a box around area of interest)
       self.plotter.SetEnableZoom(False)

       # list of (x,y) data point tuples        
       self.coordinates = []   
       for x_item in range(MAXIMUM_PLOTS):
           self.coordinates.append((x_item, (ymin+ymax)/2))

       self.queue = deque(self.coordinates)            

       if self.maxThreshold!=None:            
           self._update_max_threshold()             
       #endif           

       if self.lockThreshold!=None:            
           self._update_min_threshold()            
       #endif

       self.line = plot.PolyLine(self.coordinates, colour=plotColour, width=1)                
       self.lines[0] = (self.line)                                                     

       self.gc = plot.PlotGraphics(self.lines, title, 'Time', 'Value')
       self.plotter.Draw(self.gc, xAxis=(0, MAXIMUM_PLOTS), yAxis=(ymin, ymax))            

       self.frame1.Show(True)

    def _update_max_threshold(self):
        if self.maxThreshold!=None:
           self.maxCoordinates = []
           for x_item in range(MAXIMUM_PLOTS):
               self.maxCoordinates.append((x_item, self.maxThreshold))
           #endfor
           self.maxLine = plot.PolyLine(self.maxCoordinates, colour="green", width=1)
           self.maxMarker = plot.PolyMarker(self.maxCoordinates, colour="green", marker='dot')
           self.lines[1] = self.maxMarker 
        #endif  

   def _update_live_param(self, liveParam, minParam, maxParam):
        if minParam!=None:
            self.minThreshold = int(minParam)
            self._update_min_threshold()
        #endif

        if maxParam!=None:
            self.maxThreshold = int(maxParam)
            self._update_max_threshold() 
        #endif

        if liveParam!=None:            
            self._update_coordinates(int(liveParam))
        #endif

    def _update_coordinates(self, newValue):
        newList = []         
        for x,y in self.coordinates[1:]:            
            newList.append((x-1, y))
        #endfor
        newList.append((x, newValue))
        print "New list", newList

        self.line = (plot.PolyLine(newList, colour=self.plotColour, width=1))
        self.lines[0] = self.line
        self.coordinates = newList

    def _MyLIVE_MAGIC_refresh__(self, liveParam=None, minParam=None, maxParam=None):   
        self._update_live_param(liveParam, minParam, maxParam)
        self.gc = plot.PlotGraphics(self.lines, self.title, 'Time', 'Value')
        self.plotter.Draw(self.gc, xAxis=(0, MAXIMUM_PLOTS), yAxis=(self.ymin, self.ymax))            
        self.plotter.Refresh()            
        self.frame1.Refresh()
```