# What's the best way to plot realtime graph in a wxPanel?

Tags: python, plot, wxpython, wxwidgets

There will be approximately 400 line in each frame in 400*300 wxPanel. I used PaintDC but it performed lower than 30fps and it caused high load. Is there any alternative solution in wxPython instead of just switching PyGame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the wxPython mailing list. I doubt most users will notice if the frame rate is lower than 30 fps. You should also look at matplotlib which can be integrated into wxPython. See the following:

- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis/
- http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/EmbeddingInWx

See also the following:

- [What is the best real time plotting widget for wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457246/what-is-the-best-real-time-plotting-widget-for-wxpython)
- [Minimalistic Real-Time Plotting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401857/minimalistic-real-time-plotting-in-python)
- [dynamic plotting in wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181391/dynamic-plotting-in-wxpython)
- http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/real-time-data-plots-td2344816.html