# How to make real-time matplotlib faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, wxpython

I have an issue. I'm using matplotlib on a project to do some real-time programming, I used this library because it was suggested by my mentor although I think now it was not a good idea since I learned that matplotlib is not real-time oriented. As I was working at the lab with the lab computer, real-time made the computer slow, but not that slow as now that I'm remote working on my laptop that is 5 years old, but I don't think that's the problem. In the project, I use Python 2.7, postgresql, pandas, wxpython, etc, so you get the idea. I have a notebook with multiple tabs and in each tab I implemented one figure of mpl for each instrument I start adding. For performance things I make it stop animation and star as you go between the tabs and only if the have been started with the desirable variable.

The thing is that as I started working on my laptop, as soon as I start the real-time plotting, the applications becomes very laggy, it's mostly unusable because it jumps too much when I'm trying to interact with it, or when is running too long. Then I think it's something more of the code and how it's plot. I'm seeking a way of making it run faster. My code for plotting is the following.

```
class live_panel_2(wx.Panel):  # Real Time plotter for 2 Variable
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(live_panel_2, self).__init__(parent)
        #sns.set()  # Set Plot Style

        self.parent = parent
        self.x_axis = []  # First x-axis
        self.x2_axis = []  # Second x-axis
        self.y_axis = []  # First y-axis
        self.y2_axis = []  # Seconf y-axis
        self.line_width = 1  # Line width for plots
        self.flag = False
        self.switch = True  # Switch Flag
        self.animation = False  # Animation Flag
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(10, 3))  # Figure Size
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)  # Canvas of Figure
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.axis2 = self.axis.twinx()  # Adding Second Axis
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas)  # Adding Navigation Tool
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        self.ani = None

        self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, right=0.92, top=0.92, bottom=0.2, wspace=1)  # Figure Space Adjust
        self.axis.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')  # Format Dates
        self.axis2.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')  # Format Dates
        # self.axis.tick_params(axis='x', direction='inout', length=5, labelrotation=0)

        # Sizer Adds
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        # sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.stop)

        self.canvas.draw()

    def build(self, model, model_2, y, y2, delta, localization):  # Method that builds the plot based on info received:
        """"
        Model: Mapped Model to be Used.
        Y: Mapped parameter to be plotted.
        Delta: Plot Range
        Localization: Legend localization
        """
        self.axis.set_title(model.Datetime.name + ' vs ' + y.name + ' vs ' + y2.name)
        self.axis.set_xlabel(model.Datetime.name)
        self.axis.set_ylabel(y.name)


        # self.axis.annotate(str(value), xy=(time, value), xytext=(10, -2), textcoords='offset pixels',
        #                    bbox=dict(boxstyle=custom_box_style, alpha=0.2))

        # Set Axis 2 Format

        self.axis2.set_xlabel(model.Datetime.name)
        self.axis2.set_ylabel(y2.name)

        # self.axis2.annotate(str(value2), xy=(time, value2), xytext=(10, -2), textcoords='offset pixels',
        #                    bbox=dict(boxstyle=custom_box_style, alpha=0.2))


        # Turn of scientific notation
        self.axis.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())
        self.axis.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
        self.axis.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
        self.axis2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())
        self.axis2.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
        self.axis2.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)

        # Set legend and turn axes 2 grid off

        self.axis2.grid(False)

        if self.animation:  # If Animation is true
            self.ani._stop()  # Stop animation
            self.x_axis = []  # Make Arrays empty
            self.x2_axis = []
            self.y_axis = []
            self.y2_axis = []
        self.delta = delta  # Set Delta
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.animate,
                                           fargs=(
                                               self.x_axis, self.x2_axis, self.y_axis, self.y2_axis, model, model_2, y,
                                               y2,
                                               localization), interval=500)  # Call Animate Method.
        self.animation = True  # Set Animation to True
        self.ani._start()  # Start Animation

    def close(self):
        self.ani._stop()

    def stop(self, event):  # Stop method when changing between real-time notebook
        if self.ani != None:  # If animation have been created.
            #  If animation is running and is not current page.
            if self.flag == False and self.animation == True and self.parent != self.parent.parent.GetCurrentPage():
                self.ani.event_source.stop()  # Stop animation
                self.flag = True
                self.animation = False  # Set Animation flag to False
            # If animation is not running and is current page.
            elif self.flag == True and self.animation == False and self.parent == self.parent.parent.GetCurrentPage():
                self.ani.event_source.start()
                self.flag = False
                self.animation = True
        event.Skip()

    def mode_stop(self, event):  # Stop method when changing between views.
        if self.ani != None:
            if self.switch != True and self.parent == self.parent.parent.GetCurrentPage():
                self.ani.event_source.start()
                self.switch = True
            else:
                self.ani.event_source.stop()
                self.switch = False
        event.Skip()

    # Animation
    def animate(self, i, x_axis, x2_axis, y_axis, y2_axis, model, model2, y, y2, localization):
        # Data query
        self.now = datetime.now()  # Get Present Time
        self.now_delta = self.now - timedelta(minutes=self.delta)  # Get past time with delta.
        if not x_axis:  # If x_axis array have not been created.
            with session_scope() as s:  # Open SQL Session
                value = s.query(y).order_by(model.Datetime.desc()).filter(model.Datetime > self.now_delta).filter(
                    model.Datetime < self.now).all()  # Query Values for y array in axis 1.
                value2 = s.query(y2).order_by(model2.Datetime.desc()).filter(model2.Datetime > self.now_delta).filter(
                    model2.Datetime < self.now).all()  # Query Values for y array in axis 2.
                time = s.query(model.Datetime).order_by(model.Datetime.desc()).filter(
                    model.Datetime > self.now_delta).filter(
                    model.Datetime < self.now).all()  # Query dates for x array in axis 1.
                time2 = s.query(model2.Datetime).order_by(model2.Datetime.desc()).filter(
                    model2.Datetime > self.now_delta).filter(
                    model2.Datetime < self.now).all()  # Query date for x array in axis 2.

            # Reverse List.
            for i in reversed(value):
                y_axis.append(i[0])
            for i in reversed(value2):
                y2_axis.append(i[0])
            for i in reversed(time):
                x_axis.append(i[0])
            for i in reversed(time2):
                x2_axis.append(i[0])

        if x_axis:  # If X Axis Array Exist
            with session_scope() as s:  # Open SQL Session
                value = s.query(y).filter(model.Datetime > x_axis[
                    -1]).all()  # Query Valyes for Y array in axis 1, after the date of the last point in the array.
                value2 = s.query(y2).filter(model2.Datetime > x2_axis[
                    -1]).all()  # Query Valyes for Y array in axis 2, after the date of the last point in the array.
                time = s.query(model.Datetime).filter(model.Datetime > x_axis[
                    -1]).all()  # Query Valyes for X array in axis 1, after the date of the last point in the array.
                time2 = s.query(model2.Datetime).filter(model2.Datetime > x2_axis[
                    -1]).all()  # Query Valyes for X array in axis 2, after the date of the last point in the array.

                # Appent in Array
                for i in value:
                    y_axis.append(i[0])
                for i in value2:
                    y2_axis.append(i[0])
                for i in time:
                    x_axis.append(i[0])
                for i in time2:
                    x2_axis.append(i[0])

        # Alinate Array
        x_axis, y_axis = array_alinate(x_axis, y_axis)
        x2_axis, y2_axis = array_alinate(x2_axis, y2_axis)

        # Create Dataframe from the arrays
        data_1 = pd.DataFrame(y_axis, x_axis, [y.name], dtype=float)
        data_2 = pd.DataFrame(y2_axis, x2_axis, [y2.name], dtype=float)

        # Set Index Name to Models Datetime Name
        data_1.index.name = model.Datetime.name
        data_2.index.name = model2.Datetime.name

        # Resapmle to second if the models are from wibs-neo
        if model == (wibs_neo_monitoring or wibs_neo_particle):
            data_1 = data_1.resample('S').mean()
            data_2 = data_2.resample('S').mean()

        # Secure data points dont past delta, asuming each datapoint lapse one second.
        data_1 = data_1.iloc[-self.delta * 60:]
        data_2 = data_2.iloc[-self.delta * 60:]

        # Clear Axis
        #self.axis.clear()
        #self.axis2.clear()

        self.axis.set_xlim(min(data_1.index), max(data_1.index))
        self.axis2.set_xlim(min(data_2.index), max(data_2.index))
        line_2 = self.axis2.plot(data_2, linewidth=self.line_width, color='G', label=y2.name)
        line_1 = self.axis.plot(data_1, linewidth=self.line_width, color='B', label=y.name)

        lines = line_1 + line_2
        labels = [l.get_label() for l in lines]
        self.axis2.legend(lines, labels, loc=localization)

        # Format plot
        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', self.close)
        # tm.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Matplotlib is not made for real time plotting. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57461819/7919597

Comment: Good example with multiple scrolling plots https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/scrollingPlots.py

Comment: Hi @Joe, i was looking around to re-write in my code in PyQTGrapth and right now i'm using python 2.7 to do this. I got this error `Exception: PyQtGraph requires one of PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide; none of these packages could be imported.`

Comment: and if i'm good, PyQTGraph is not compatible with wxpython

Comment: They are two different frameworks, Qt is a very well know and mighty toolkit. Not sure what your project is aiming at. If you are trying something professional, you might be better of changing to Qt. https://github.com/ZELLMECHANIK-DRESDEN/ShapeOut/issues/150

Comment: There are nice Python bindings for Qt https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: @Joe, i see what you are aiming at. Early in the project i tried to use Qt, but as far as i know, Qt is not compatible with python 2.7, or it is?

Comment: From what I read here https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt it should work on 2 and 3.

Comment: But when you are starting from scratch and there are no dependencies, the first thing I would drop is 2.7. It's time :)

Comment: @Joe, that's the thing my project manager wanted this project to be in python 2.7 since it would be stable, I've been working in this project since june last year. I'm pretty forward in the projet and changing the whole Gui frame work and version of python is going to be a pain.

Comment: Ok. But then you'd be better of by dropping Matplotlib for some wxpython thing. I https://stackoverflow.com/a/457781/7919597     or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856540/whats-the-best-way-to-plot-realtime-graph-in-a-wxpanel

Comment: How real-time is your application in fps? 30? 50? or 1?

Comment: @Joe in fact i think i may found the problem. In the animate function witch have the axis plots, im calling it again an again instead of the usual `set_data`, but im trying to change it and axis does not have that method, only pyplot but i dont see how i can manage 2 lines in pyplot

Comment: It should be a method of the plot you are drawing (plt.plot returns a Line2D artist), not of pyplot or the axis. see https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/